# Secure thunderbird profile with admin rights

Tags: permissions, thunderbird

The goal is to make sure that, even if somebody is logged into the session, without knowing the password, he cannot access thunderbird saved mail.
(on the other side, the hdd content is encrypted)

I thought that the simplest way would be to remove permission for .thunderbird from the user, so that launching thunderbird with access to the profile would require sudo, and similarly access to saved mail via the file manager would require sudo.

What would be the setup to do something like this? I.e., it requires to also ask for sudo when using chmod or any other means to modify permissions. Is it possible to make something like this work? 
(complicated setup is fine as long as usage stays simple)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Running thunderbird as an admin user is a **Bad Idea**, especially since it is something that is often left running in the background. An attacker finding your computer with an admin-priviledged copy of thunderbird open could (for example) write a hostile script as an email, and use admin privileges to save it as text over an existing system executable.

I would in general consider disk encryption (along with a fairly fast system lock time) adequate in this situation, but if you're feeling paranoid just don't keep local copies of mail.

- Disable saving mail passwords (or at least use a master password): `Edit->Preferences->Security->Passwords`
- Configure IMAP accounts not to save local copies of messages (`Edit->Account Settings->ACCOUNT->Synchronisation & Storage`).

Answer (score 0):

Other solution to security is create any partition or file block encrypted, for example witch truecrypt you can create it, and move /home/user/.thunderbird folder to /path/encrypted/.thunderbird  and create a link intro /home/user/.thunderbird (in this case .thunderbird is a symbolic link: ln -s )

I hope helper you.